# Action after writing to txt

Tags: python, variables

Is there anyway I can check, once that the .txt file has been written? Is this able to be done with a while condition?

For example:

```
writetotxt = open(mytxt, 'w')
writetotxt.write('Line 1' + '\n')
writetotxt.write('Line 2')
writetotxt.close()

def txtwritten():
    firstline = linecache.getline(mytxt, 1)
    secline = linecache.getline(mytxt, 2)
    check = firstline + secline
```

But, while the process, it returns a blank result. When it is finished writing to text file, then it displays line 1 and 2.

Can a for condition be set to determine whether it is finished writing to the txt?

Answer (score 2):

Also look at the `flush()` file method call and the `buffering` argument to `open`.

Two reasons that trying to read immediately after writing:

1. you're not opening the file to allow reading (need to open with mode `w+` to allow reading)
2. files are buffered by default: calls to `write()` add to the buffer; until the buffer fills up, a `flush()` call is made, or the file is closed, the contents of the buffer will not actually be written to disk.